# IIS web.config url rewriting

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm using the following rule in my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
    <rules>
     <rule name="rewrite">
      <match url="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?year={R:1}&amp;item={R:2}" />
     </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It works.

But I need to show a 404 error if user writes one or more letters in the second query (*item*), e.g. 1b, or 1bla, etc.

It should only be allowed a (positive) number and, possibly, a query like *?utm_source=anothersite* or *?ref=anothersite* etc.

In other words, url should be:

*www.mysite.com/{year}/{item}*

where {year} and {item} are both mandatory and could be numbers only, no other elements allowed (e.g.: *www.mysite.com/{year}/{item}/{somethingelse}*), except *?key=value*.

How can I change *match url* value in order to achieve that result?

Thanks.

Comment: "But I need to show a 404 error if user writes one or more letters in the second query (item), e.g. 1b, or 1bla, etc." Your web application receives the wrong input, so it should redirect to a 404 page. That has little to do with IIS, or the rewrite rule any more.

Comment: @ Lex Li - On my server, if the user writes, e.g., www.mysite.com/1a/1 then he gets a 404 error, but if he writes, e.g., www.mysite.com/1/1a then the url is accepted - And it should not. That's what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a "$" to the end your pattern.

```
<match url="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$" />
```

This is my tested result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works fine on my side. You can check my answer above. please show me your error message.

Comment: Using <match url="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$" /> on my website, I get a 404 error (customized page). Believe me. What's the "$" meaning/purpose?

Comment: "$" means match the end position of the input string. If you do not add "$", then “1/1a” can also match successfully. About 404 error, please post your detailed error information.

Comment: Issue solved. It was due to a conflict between two web.config files (one in the root and the other in a subfolder of my site). Thanks for your answer: it helped me.